# Problem with CruiseControl.net configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I started using ccnet to build my project. This is quite new issue for me so I have some problems.

First thing: Why does ccnet copy directory with my project to another directory (ccnet creates new folder named the same as project name included in ccnet.config file and copies to them directory with my project)

Second thing: Dashboard page cannot show reports for recent build (When I click on any item in recent build then I get page: "The page Cannot be found" I suppose that page cannot link files with logs. but I don't know how to link it.
I create one publisher:

```
<publishers>
<xmllogger logDir="c:\Branches" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just a question,  does the batch file "C:\Branches\Scripts\Build Release.bat" perform that step?

Because I can't see anything obvious within the CruiseControl config to copy the files into "c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\Sever\TestProject"...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the 'first thing' if you can elaborate on it I'll try to help.
On our system it performs an SVN checkout of the code to a specified location and builds it there. Even though our CCNet installation is on the same box as the SVN repository it still needs somewhere separate to build the project.

On the 'second thing' it sounds like you have not set the `<webURL>` element properly - not a major problem. If you can post your config file that may help (with both issues).

Our CCNet installation pretty much worked out of the box but it is pretty fussy about it's config files. Have you made any changes to the dashboard.config file or is it as installed?

**[Edit in response to posted config file]**

I can't see anything in this config that will cause CCNet to copy the project to c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\Server\TestProject. It could be something to do with the way you are calling devenv in your batch file - do you specify any paths in there?

Based on your config file and assuming you have an out of the box installation, your `<webURL>` element should read something like this:

```
<webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/server/local/testProject/ViewProjectReport.aspx</webURL>
```

On top of all that I would highly recommend that you drop the use of .bat files and devenv.exe for building your projects. Although this is the way I started with CCNet I quickly found that using NAnt and MSBuild well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I Try explain it more.
I have my local copy of repository on the path: "c:\Branches\trunk"

here is my config file:

```
<cruiseControl>
<project name="testProject">
  <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/</webURL>
  <triggers>
    <intervalTrigger name="interval trigger" seconds="600" initialSeconds="30" />
  </triggers>
  <sourcecontrol type="svn" autoGetSource="true">
    <trunkUrl>http://********/svn/general/provider/prototype/Trunk</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Branches\Trunk</workingDirectory>
    <password>***********</password>
    <username>*************</username>
  </sourcecontrol>
  <tasks>
    <exec>
      <description>Compile program</description>
      <baseDirectory>C:\Branches\Trunk\</baseDirectory>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>9000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      <executable>C:\Branches\Scripts\Build Release.bat</executable>
    </exec>
  </tasks>
  <publishers>
    <xmllogger logDir="C:\Branches\Trunk\Logs" />
  </publishers>
  <state type="state" directory="C:\Branches\Trunk\Logs"></state>
</project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

I didn't change anything in dashboard.config File. 
cnet copy all folder c:\Branches\Trunk
to new folder c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\Sever\TestProject

First problem was cause because in previous version of config file i use filesystem as sourcecontrol. Right now this problem don't occur. 
Second problem is not resolved, But I have one Idea, Does any configuration files should be placed in virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

In build Release script I just call devenv to compile my project